# C++ Builder XE7: ShellControls

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe7

last time I jumped from cpp builder 6 to xe7, and I can't find `ShellListView` and `ShellTreeView`. I searched through whole forum, but I couldn't find answear. Can someone explain me where is it, cause I'm looking for it about 3h. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

- locate the `<DemoDirInstall Path>\CPP\Apps\ShellControls` folder

  (`<DemoDirInstall Path>` is "somewhere near" `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\XXX\Demos\`)
- load the `ShellControls.groupproj`
- build `bcbshlctrls.bpl` (the runtime package)
- build and install `dclshlctrls.bpl` (the designtime package)

The directory also contains code that demonstrates the creation of components which use the Windows Shell API.